# How to delete in terminal from "/" to "/"?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, kitty

Im using Kitty emulator and bash shell.

I know that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> I can delete **a word** in terminal (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>). But what if I have something like this:

```
sh /home/user/dir1/dir2/file.sh
```

I just want to delete the `file.sh`?

I can't delete with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> because then the **whole line will be deleted** and I don't want to delete it manually.

Any advice how to delete from only one path element?

Comment: Similar: [How to delete a word next of last slash](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/167071)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are using bash, with the default Emacs style editing. Then an [Emacs cheat sheet](https://kapeli.com/cheat_sheets/Emacs.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/index) may be helpful - you could do `Alt+Backspace` (backward-kill-word) to delete back to the start of the last word.

Answer (score 2):

In `bash` and other applications that use `readline` as their line editor, whatever character is bound to the `werase` tty line discipline setting (see output of `stty -a`) ends up bound to the `unix-word-rubout` readline widget which behaves similarly (deletes a whitespace separated word backward), and in that case, as long as the character is bound to `werase`, any attempt to bind it to a different widget is ignored AFAICT.

On most systems, `werase` is `^W` in the  default tty settings.

So, in order to be able to rebind `^W` to something else in readline, you need first to change that tty setting:

```
stty werase '^O'
```

to bind `werase` to `^O` instead or:

```
stty werase ''
```

To disable it altogether.

And then you'll be able to do:

```
bind '"\C-w": backward-kill-word'
```

Or add `"\C-w": backward-kill-word` to your `~/.inputrc` for that to apply to all applications using `readline`, not just `bash`.

Then, ^W would delete words in the way you like (well, where *words* are defined as sequences of letters or digits, not even underscore).

That means however you won't be able to use ^W to delete a word in applications that don't have their own line editor.

Alternatively, you could use `zsh` instead of `bash` where all word motion / killing widgets are entirely configurable.

Or as already [mentioned by @AndreBeaud](/a/715608) use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> (which usually send `^[^H` or `^[^?`, the latter in `kitty`) which is already bound to `backward-kill-word` by default in readline's emacs mode.

Answer (score 1):

#### Set a binding to `unix-filename-rubout` in .inputrc

```
"\C-b":unix-filename-rubout
```

This way `CTRL B` is mapped to deleting backward till slash or space.

This is a better solution then `ALT BACKSPACE`, because `ALT BACKSPACE` will not delete till backward slash when there are underscores in the path.

Underscores are considered a word boundary.

Of course you can choose another keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score -3):

[image: Keyboard text shortcuts in terminal]

These may be helpful.
You can find more shortcuts in terminal by navigating to "help, contents, advanced settings, keyboard shortcuts"