# How to delete a region in the command line?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, readline

I just [learned](https://genius.it/27955694/www.masteringemacs.org/article/keyboard-shortcuts-every-command-line-hacker-should-know-about-gnu-readline) that command lines have marks,
just like emacs.
But,
unlike emacs,
`C-w` doesn't delete the region,
it only deletes one word backwards.
Is there a `readline` equivalent for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both readline and zsh, that's the same `kill-region` widget as in emacs or tcsh, but not bound by default since, contrary to tcsh, they both chose to have `^W` align with the `werase` of the tty device line discipline instead.

See `info bash kill-region` for bash/readline of `info zsh kill-region` in zsh.

To bind it to `^W`, in zsh (like in tcsh):

```
bindkey '^W' kill-region
```

in zsh (like in tcsh).

In bash, you need first to configure the line discipline to use a different character for `werase` or disable `werase` altoger (but then you won't be able to kill word from the tty's own line editor):

```
stty werase '^O'
# or:
stty werase '' # disable
bind '"\C-w": kill-region'
```

or add `"\C-w": kill-region` to your `~/.inputrc` for it to affect all applications that use readline. That's with the same limitation; `werase` must be changed to something else before readline is initialised, so in the case of bash, before bash is started.

Comment: Thanks. It should be noted that one has to undefine `^w` from the tty configuration in order to be able to use it in readline: `stty wearse undef`.

Comment: @ychaouche, ah yes, I had forgotten about that annoying behaviour of readline. See also [How to delete in terminal from "/" to "/"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/715610).

Comment: Thanks again @stéphane-chazelas. After trying it, I quickly missed the old behavior of `^w`, so I left it as it was, and defined another key combo for kill-region (`^h` that I didn't use)